# how to get cell info of a developer express data gridview in testcomplete (cardView)?

Tags: .net, datagridview, vbscript, devexpress, testcomplete

i am trying to get the cell info of a developer express Data grid View (card layout). i am trying to get the bounds of a particular cell(card). i tried implementing the following code:

```
gridobj.MainView.get_ViewInfo.Cards.CardFieldInfoBy(RowHandle,Column).Bounds
```

after using the above code i am still not getting the card bound, infact the card property itself is not getting displayed in the function library (drop down ) . is there any way i can get the bounds of a cell(Card).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this code:

var cardIndex = 3
  var grid = ...
  var card = grid.MainView.ViewInfo.Cards.Item(cardIndex)
  var bounds = card.Bounds

Answer (score 0):

well i finally got the solution for it , found an alternative.

```
gridobj.MainView.get_ViewInfo.RowsInfo.GetInfoByHandle(rowindex).Cells.Item(coloumindex)
```

and for data gridview of cards :

```
grid.MainView.get_ViewInfo.VisibleCards.Item(rowindex)
```

this worked for me:

```
use Bounds.left and Bounds.Top
```